# Errors when building LLVM 3.4 and clang

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, installation, llvm, llvm-clang

So I've followed the instructions on the "Getting Started Quickly" guide for LLVM 3.4 here, http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary,  for LLVM and clang to install, however I've ran into some errors when running the "make" command.

It took about 45 minutes for the "make" command to process through everything and then there were some errors that appeared near the end, which I have attached the screenshots for. After running "make check-all", it would say that there are two errors.

I also saw the versions of LLVM that came with Ubuntu 13.04 and it has versions up to 3.2 that come precompiled, at least that is what it showed when I did the "sudo apt-cache search llvm" command, however, I need at least version 3.3 installed.

It seems that these errors may be due to the g++ compiler crashing at a certain point, so I was wondering, is there a work around for me to get at least LLVM 3.3 and clang installed?

I've been searching for the past three days all over the web, including this site, to find a solution for this, however, I can't seem to find any solutions anywhere, so I am asking on here. I would greatly appreciate any help that I can get to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: Your `make check-all` is failing because `make` is not completing successfully(based on 2nd screenshot). Instead of pasting screenshots here, it will be better to put the text so that we can see what is going wrong. Try to do `make` again and paste the relevant portion of the output(which shows the exact error message, not just the last line which says there is one error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my issue, it seems that by doing the build from the source code that was downloaded using SVN, it was downloading the 3.4 version, which is still in the development stage and not necessarily being supported by Ubuntu 13.04 yet.

I simply just downloaded the 3.3 version files from the LLVM site and did the build with that and it worked!